# zoom in/out not possible: always focus on my position flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps-api-3

I just started learning flutter and I am trying to build a mobile app using google maps.
I am following a tutorial which is bulding an app that track my position all the time:

[image: example]

It is working pretty good, the problem is that when ever I try to zoom in/out it take me back to my position with the default zoom **even if I am not mooving**.

I am trying to be able to zoom in/out **even if i am moving and tak me back my position only when i click on button**.

here is the source code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Maps',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Map Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamSubscription _locationSubscription;
  Location _locationTracker = Location();
  Marker marker;
  Circle circle;
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  static final CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  Future<Uint8List> getMarker() async {
    ByteData byteData = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).load("assets/car_icon.png");
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  void updateMarkerAndCircle(LocationData newLocalData, Uint8List imageData) {
    LatLng latlng = LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude);
    this.setState(() {
      marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("home"),
          position: latlng,
          rotation: newLocalData.heading,
          draggable: false,
          zIndex: 2,
          flat: true,
          anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(imageData));
      circle = Circle(
          circleId: CircleId("car"),
          radius: newLocalData.accuracy,
          zIndex: 1,
          strokeColor: Colors.blue,
          center: latlng,
          fillColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(70));
    });
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {

      Uint8List imageData = await getMarker();
      var location = await _locationTracker.getLocation();

      updateMarkerAndCircle(location, imageData);

      if (_locationSubscription != null) {
        _locationSubscription.cancel();
      }


      _locationSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged().listen((newLocalData) {
        if (_controller != null) {
          _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
              bearing: 192.8334901395799,
              target: LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
              tilt: 0,
              zoom: 18.00)));
          updateMarkerAndCircle(newLocalData, imageData);
        }
      });

    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        debugPrint("Permission Denied");
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_locationSubscription != null) {
      _locationSubscription.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
        markers: Set.of((marker != null) ? [marker] : []),
        circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle] : []),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },

      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
          onPressed: () {
            getCurrentLocation();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me guys!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this
Declare a variable that hold you position as your location changes

```
Map _position;
```

The in your location change listener

```
_locationSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged().listen((newLocalData) {
  setState(() {
    _position = {
      "lat": newLocalData.latitude,
      "lng": newLocalData.longitude,
      "heading": newLocalData.heading,
    };
  });
  if (_controller != null) updateMarkerAndCircle(newLocalData, imageData);
});
```

Finally, call this method each time you want to center the map to your current position

```
void _gotoCurrentPosition() {
    if (null != _controller && null != _position) {
      _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
         bearing: _position["heading"],
         target: LatLng(_position["lat"], _position["lng"]),
         tilt: 0,
         zoom: 18.00),
       ),);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what should it be if I want to be able to zoom in/out and only get my position if i click on the button?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is your application is focusing on your location and when you try to override an action it will continue to focus on the first taste which focusing your location. you have to separate your methods so when your application focusing on your location, you can still cancel the focus by override the first method onTap or onCameraMove.

```
_locationSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged().listen((newLocalData) {
    if (_controller != null) {
      _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
          bearing: 192.8334901395799,
          target: LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
          tilt: 0,
          zoom: 18.00)));
      updateMarkerAndCircle(newLocalData, imageData);
    }
  });
```

This is the reason why the maps take your back to your location when you are trying to move it, because the camera always animated to your location position